# Java 2D additive colors

Tags: java, colors, 2d, addition

Are there any way to draw with additive colors using Graphics2D. E. g. if cyan and red lines overlap, their intersection is of white color? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to enable [`XOR mode`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#setXORMode%28java.awt.Color%29), but the results are not well defined and it may not do what you want.

Perhaps [using](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#setComposite%28java.awt.Composite%29) an [`AlphaComposite`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/AlphaComposite.html) you can achieve what you want? The outcome is more predictable.

Comment: The output from a AlphaComposite is maybe more predictable than XOR mode, but it is not really "additive color mixing", more of "write one over the other" (if I understand the existing modes right). Creating an own Composite implementation may be a better way. (Pay attention, you need to have a proper AWTPermission to do this.)

Comment: Yes, custom composite is the way. Too slow, but okay for my purposes. Thanks.